# How do you make this triangle made with css face up?

Tags: css

There is this triangle that is made with css: http://jsfiddle.net/W3hNx/1/

How can I make it face up? :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Neat website, pretty handy in situations exactly like this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change `border-top` to `border-bottom` in `.triangle`. [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3hNx/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
border-top: 30px solid green;
```

to

```
border-bottom: 30px solid green;
```

in `.triangle` selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
border-left: 25px solid transparent;
border-right: 25px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 30px solid green;
```

this will make the triangle face up